# If condition is not working for some reason

Tags: python, if-statement

```
while True:
    inp = input("Say hi bruh!: ").lower
    if inp == "hi":
        print("Okay")
        break
    else:
        print("Not Okay")
        continue
```

It either doesn't enter the condition or something.  I know Python for a while and can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: `input("Say hi bruh!: ").lower()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joran stated in the comment, you're missing the parentheses after `lower`. Once you add those your loop will work. Python cannot successfully interpret your variable `inp` without them.

```
while True:
    inp = input("Say hi bruh!: ").lower()
    if inp == "hi":
        print("Okay")
        break
    else:
        print("Not Okay")
        continue
```

Comment: Technically, it can interpret it.  However, you get a bound method which doesn't compare equal to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a bracket after lower as it is a function. It is necessary to put a bracket in case of functions.

```
while True:
    inp = input("Say hi bruh!: ").lower()
    if inp == "hi":
        print("Okay")
        break
    else:
        print("Not Okay")
        continue
```